# Can't cast Template subclass to a different Template instantiation

Tags: c++, class, templates, casting

suppose having a Template `stack<class T, int maxElements` which have a subclass `Entry`, which will build the Linked List for the stack, so something like this:

```
template <class T, int maxElements>
class Stack{
private: 
     class Entry{
        friend class Stack;
        T info;
        Entry* next;
     };
     Entry* first;
public:
    template<class U, int n>
    void append(const Stack<U, n>& s){
          if(isEmpty()) first = s.first; /* here is the problem*/
          ....
    }

};
```

So, the problem is in the line marked, and it's `assigning to 'Stack<char, 100>::Entry *' from incompatible type 'Stack<char, 10>::Entry *const'`, and that because it's building a "class" Entry for each template instantiation, but the point is that Entry doesn't depends from the `maxElement` parameter, so I would like to know if there is a way to tell this to the compiler.
So far, the only way i can think that can do this, is to take out the class from the template, and making itself a template based only on T

PS: i know i'm sharing memory in the line where i'm having the error, one thing at time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that different template instantiations are different types. With that, nested types (`Entry` in this case) are different types as well.

The solution is just as simple: Move parts to a (private) baseclass that only depends on the type:

```
template<typename T>
class StackBase {
protected:
    struct Entry {
        T info;
        Entry* next;
    };
};
```

Then you derive from this baseclass:

```
template<typename T, int maxElements>
class Stack: private StackBase<T> {
    ...
};
```

Comment: is there a way to "hide" this StackBase class? because what i was trying to achieve is to don't give access to the others programmer to some class that i use to "build" mine

Comment: No. A common way to document that in code is to put it into a nested `detail` namespace to document that it's not a public API but an implementation detail.

Comment: is there any reason behind the "struct" instead of "class" in the StackBase class?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the `friend` declaration can't be implemented easily. Also, that friend declaration is pretty silly: Since only code from `Stack<>` can even see the nested `Entry` class, you can as well make all members public. It doesn't make the members accessible to anyone else.

Comment: thanks, and how can i access the Entry struct from the Stack? because you are inheriting StackBase as private and Entry is in the private interface

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my side. You can either make it `protected` or even `public` (when it's made clear that this isn't part of the public API).